# C++ auto-generated copy constructors with const and non-const refs

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo &) {
        std::cout << "Foo(Foo &)" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Bar { Foo m; };

int main() {
    Bar b;
    Bar b2(b);
}
```

If this code is run, *Foo(Foo &)* message is written. Ok, as Foo doesn't have `Foo(const Foo &)` constructor, `Base(Base &)` constructor is generated for `Base`. Now, if we add the following to the definition of `Foo`:

```
Foo(const Foo &) {
    std::cout << "Foo(const Foo &)" << std::endl;
}
```

the *Foo(const Foo &)* message will be written. Ok, now Foo has copy-constructor with const ref parameter, so Base(const Base &) is generated by the compiler. But, if I declare `Foo(const Foo &)` as explicitly deleted:

```
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
```

Then the program won't compile with the following errors:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:15:13: error: use of deleted function 'Bar::Bar(const Bar&)'
     Bar b2(b);
             ^
prog.cc:11:8: note: 'Bar::Bar(const Bar&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct Bar { Foo m; };
        ^~~
prog.cc:11:8: error: use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
prog.cc:8:5: note: declared here
     Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
     ^~~
```

In the first revision of the code, if `Foo(const Foo&)` is not generated, why don't we have an error, like in the third revision? And if it's generated, why isn't it called (producing no output message), like in the second revision?

Comment: What is this `Base` you're speaking of, which appears nowhere in your code?

Comment: "Deleted" doesn't mean "absent". Deleted overloads still take part in overload resolution. In some sense that's the whole point. If you didn't want the constructor, don't say it (as in your very first example).

Comment: You are wrong in your first assumption: the compiler will never generate a constructor with a non-const ref argument.  It generates a default base(const base&) constructor.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, my confusion was because I mixed these two notions, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A copy-constructor is implicitly declared and defined if there is no user-declared copy-ctor, move-ctor, or move-assignment-operator.

It is of the form `X(const X&)` if all virtual bases, direct bases and non-static data members `T` declare a copy-ctor accepting a `const T&`.
Otherwise it is of the form `X(X&)`.

An implicitly declared copy-ctor is defaulted, and a defaulted copy-ctor is deleted if the default-definition (member-wise copy) is ill-formed.

You got an error because the sub-objects copy-ctor accepting const& is deleted, making the containing classes copy-ctor deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you add that below to your code

```
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
```

and tried to call with

```
 Bar b2(b);
```

you code with  `Foo(const Foo&) = delete;`

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;

    Foo(Foo &) {
        std::cout << "Foo(Foo &)" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Bar { Foo m; };

int main() {
    Bar b;
    Bar b2(b);
}
```

> You are trying to call  implicitly deleted copy constructor of Bar